# MySQL: Composite Primary Key, Unique and simple indexes for relational table

Tags: mysql

I have read tons of answers but have not found an explanation yet. I want to know how to correctly set indexes on a specific table.

I have relational table that connects between two other tables and also contains some data in it:

[image: Allocation table]

[image]

I want to know how to set indexes correctly based on this points:

- the `id` column is required (because I am using the Laravel framework that requires the `id` primary key).
- `room_id`, `channel_id` and `date` need to be unique as the 3 together represent the row.
- `room_id` and `channel_id` are foreign keys.
- the `date` column must be indexed as its a common search column.

I come up with this but I'm pretty sure its redundant and wrong:

- composite primary key: `id`, `room_id`, `channel_id`.
- composite unique index: `room_id`, `channel_id`, `date`.
- index: `room_id`
- index: `channel_id`
- index: `date`

Additional question: Does `date` need to be part of the composite primary key?

Would like to know hot to correctly set the primary key(s), indexes and uniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i would do to meet your requierments:

- primary key: `id`
- index: `room_id`
- index: `channel_id`
- unique index: `date`, `room_id`, `channel_id`

Explanation:

1. `id` is auto increment, so it will be enough for PK.
2. `room_id` and `channel_id` are useless in PK if `id` is on first place.
3. Every index contains the PK. So the PK should be as small as possible.
4. If the unique index starts with `date`, you can use it for date search. So an separate `date` index is not needed.

Comment: interesting, so the first unique value behaves differently that the subsequent ones? and regarding keeping the PK small, can I take this as a general rule of thumb? meaning that if there's a similar relational table where an id PK is present, it is better to leave the foreign keys only as indexes?

Comment: For the first question please take a look at [Multiple-Column Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html): "MySQL can use multiple-column indexes for queries that test all the columns in the index, or queries that test **just the first column**, ..". To the second question: No - i would not take it as a general rule. But in your case and in most cases, where an auto increment coulmn is defined, the AI column should be the PK. And no - there is no need to put a FK into PK just because it's an FK.